# How do I create a dynamic query using pouchdb (couchdb probably the same thing)?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I have a dynamic query that I'd like to write using PouchDB, but I am finding it difficult to translate how I might achieve this using an SQL database compared to PouchDB.

I have number of documents of type 'session' in PouchDB, and there needs to be a complex search for this type of document. I'd like to filter on things like title (strings that start with a provided value), status, the owner, equipment id, a start date, an end date, and a few other things.

Now, I know I could emit an array key, something like:

```
            document.views = {
                by_title_status_owner: {
                    map: function(document) {
                        if(document._id.startsWith('session')) {
                            emit([
                                document.title.toUpperCase(),
                                document.status.text.toUpperCase(),
                                document.owner.refId
                            ], null);
                        }
                    }.toString()
                }
            };
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to make a query using `startkey` and `endkey`. I am trying stuff like this:

```
                startkey: [
                    (filters.title || '').toUpperCase(),
                    (filters.status || '').toUpperCase(),
                    (filters.owner || '')
                ],
                endkey: [
                    (filters.title || '').toUpperCase() + '\uffff',
                    (filters.status || '').toUpperCase() + '\uffff',
                    (filters.owner || '').toUpperCase() + '\uffff'
                ],
```

But it only seems to filter on the *first* index - meaning it's correctly filtering on the title, but when searching by the status or owner, the query returns all of the results.

I think the problem is that I really want to provide different emit array keys and provide different startkey/endkey combinations based on what the user has inputted, but this seems extremely hard to do with PouchDB.

For example, let's say the user typed in 'Lig' for their `title` search and selected `CLOSED` for status. That would mean the startkey should look like ['LIG', 'CLOSED'] and the endkey might look like ['LIG\uffff', 'CLOSED']. But does this mean I have to emit every single permutation of key indexes to match this dynamic startkey/endkey?

Here is my first attempt at this, and I haven't even added the 2+ parameter emited keys.....

```
        getAllByCriteria: function(filters) {
            var startkey = [], endkey = [];

            if(filters.title) {
                startkey.push((filters.title || '').toUpperCase());
                endkey.push((filters.title || '').toUpperCase() + '\uffff');
            }

            if(filters.status) {
                startkey.push((filters.status).toUpperCase());
                endkey.push((filters.status).toUpperCase());
            }

            if(filters.owner) {
                startkey.push(filters.owner);
                endkey.push(filters.owner);
            }

            return Database.instance().query('session_indexes/by_criteria', {
                startkey: startkey,
                endkey: endkey,
                include_docs: true
            }).then(function(result) {
                return _(result.rows).map(function(row) {
                    return Session.fromDocument(row.doc, new Session());
                });
            });
        },
```

and:

```
        db.upsert('_design/session_indexes', function(document) {
            document.views = {
                by_criteria: {
                    map: function(document) {
                        if(document._id.startsWith('session')) {
                            emit([], null)
                            emit([document.title.toUpperCase()], null);
                            emit([document.status.text.toUpperCase()], null);
                            emit([document.owner.refId], null);
                        }
                    }.toString()
                }
            };

            return document;
        });
```

I'm really confused. I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of view and list.

1. Emit keys like `["title", doc.title.toUpperCase()]` , `["status", doc.status.toUpperCase()]` using map fn, say `indexfn`.
2. Create _list fn, say `filter` that accepts query like `{field1:"value1", field2:"value2"...}` – lists can receive custom query params unlike map fns. Your filter must drop rows if they do not match. Surely to make filtering possible your _list must receive full (or somehow trimmed) set of fields from view fn.
3. Perform request like `/_design/ddoc/_list/filter/_view/indexfn?startkey=["field1","val1"] & endkey=["field1","val1z"] & filter={"field2":"val2", "field3":"val3"}`

This approach is reasonable when your _list receives, say, not more then thousand rows from view – piping data from view through _lists fn to end user is quiet slow.

So if you have more or less alphbetically distributed data set with ~1M records, you can have good performance if you send startkey that is 3 or more chars long.